# "Error decoding the received TLS packet" when cloning into git repository

Tags: linux, git, github, debian

I am experiencing an error when trying to clone into the https://github.com/zulip/zulip.git repository.

As far as I have looked this question has not been answered yet.

-I have tried raising the http/https buffer without success using:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
git config --global https.postBuffer 524288000
```

-The error always occurs @53% arround 100MiB in.

```
Cloning into 'zulip'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 342136, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1589/1589), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (719/719), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): Error decoding the received TLS packet.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

EDIT:
I have done a bit testing and I seem to be getting this error whenever I try to clone a very large repository.
-I tried cloning the https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster repository and got the same error;
-Then I tried with an old and very small repository of mine (https://github.com/LFBianchi/RPyNCalc) and it works like a charm;
-Just to be sure I forked the github.com/zulip/zulip.git and tried cloning it from my version and got the same exact error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Do you use a proxy? In some companies you are forced to use a proxy. The proxy may terminate the connection after a time limit. In this case you may need to ask your IT stuff.

Comment: I am not currently using any proxies, I am running an almost new instalation of BunsenLabs with Debian 10.5.
Thank you for the response!

Comment: I seem to be getting this error whenever I try to clone a very large repository. I tried cloning the https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster repository and got the same error, then I tried with an old repository of mine (https://github.com/LFBianchi/RPyNCalc) and it works like a charm.
Just to be sure I forked the https://github.com/zulip/zulip.git and tried cloning it and got the same error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this information. As I already wrote I suspect that your network might use a proxy/firewall that terminates the connection after a time limit. Some company networks may use a transparent proxy, i.e. your traffic might get redirected to the proxy automatically without any configuration on your system. Are you doing this in a company network or in your own network? Can you test the same with a different network connection or at a different location?

Comment: Well, I am at my home network but the provider (TalkTalk) has been known to do some dodgy things. I will try it on another connection. Also, I updated the information on the post, thank you for the reminder.

Comment: Consider using ssh instead of https. A lot of man-in-the-middle proxies that pretend not to be in the middle, but are in the middle, and actually *break* https, don't attempt to stand in the middle of ssh sessions (because they can't) and hence don't break ssh connections.

Comment: You should add **all** relevant information to the question, so the information about your provider as well. A user that did not follow the question from the start should not be required to read all the comments to understand your question and background.

Comment: Just set up an SSH connection, apparently there is a proxie on the TalkTalk modem that is acting up. Thank you for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by switching to SSH instead of HTTPS.